# How to access multiple values in request body of django?

Tags: django

I want to select multiple values for an attribute in my Django website.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)
    print(request.POST['category'])
```

The output of the above code is when I select the second and third category together is -

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['HYArlTZpPYIDX404ImuX4UjzC03qaa3zTa18Wd7hVw2AYaMln8ZaVfaJ8TsNtbZp'], 'category': ['2', '3']}>
3
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is multiple items you are sending in POST request then use `request.POST.getlist('category')` if it is single item then `request.POST.get('category')`